# Deleting first instance of a column after group by in sas proc sql

Tags: sas

I have the following SAS dataset.

| correlation | policynum | risknum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | Y |
| A | X | Y |
| A | X | Y |
| B | X | Y |
| B | X | Y |
| B | X | Y |
| B | X | L |
| B | X | L |
| B | X | L |
| C | Z | M |
| C | Z | M |
| C | Z | M |
| D | Z | M |
| D | Z | M |
| D | Z | M |

In SAS, I want to filter the above dataset so I get my final output as:

| correlation | policynum | risknum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | X | Y |
| B | X | Y |
| B | X | Y |
| B | X | L |
| B | X | L |
| B | X | L |
| D | Z | M |
| D | Z | M |
| D | Z | M |

i.e. for each group of `policynum` and `risknum`, if multiple values exist for `correlation`, I want to keep the second value and get rid of the first value.

If only a single value of `correlation` exists for a group of `policynum` and `risknum`, I want to retain that group in my final output too.

What would be the best way to do this? It might be something simple as I am relatively new to SAS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order of the correlation values, in sort order, is the same ordering as they appear row-wise in the data set you can use SQL.  Otherwise, SQL, being based on set theory, which does not have implicit row numbers, can not be used.  A DATA step with DOW loop can be used.

Example:

FYI, one common situation in which SAS coders use the phrase 'DOW loop' is when SET & BY statements occur inside a DO loop.

```
data have;
input correlation $ policynum $ risknum $;
datalines;
A   X   Y
A   X   Y
A   X   Y
B   X   Y
B   X   Y
B   X   Y
B   X   L
B   X   L
B   X   L
C   Z   M
C   Z   M
C   Z   M
D   Z   M
D   Z   M
D   Z   M
;

/* keep last group of a nested group */

* SQL can be used only if correlation wanted is ALWAYS highest valued correlation;

    proc sql;
      create table want as
      select * from have
      group by policynum, risknum
      having correlation = max(correlation)
      ;

* DATA Step DOW loops can be used when correlation wanted is last occurring correlation within by group;

    data want;
      do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.policynum);
        set have;
        by policynum risknum notsorted; /* presume at least contiguous */
      end;
      _want_correlation = correlation;

      do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
        set have;
        if _want_correlation = correlation then OUTPUT;
      end;
    run;
```

Comment: Thanks Richard! My correlation was such that the value I wanted to retain was the highest valued correlation, so your proc sql suggestion worked like a charm.